# Python OpenCV (cv2) VideoCapture.read() Unspecified error in NumpyAllocator::allocate

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am new to OpenCV and I am using the python version of it to read out the frames of a video so that I can do some analysis on them. I am reading an mp4 video file and looping through the frames to save them off like so:

```
import cv2
cv2Cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)
frames = []
cnt = 0 
while 1:
    # get the next frame form the video 
    ret, frame = cv2Cap.read()
    cnt+=1
    print 'Count: ' + str(cnt)
    if not ret: 
        break # means ret was false so break out of the loop 
    cv2.imshow('Frames', frame)
    # show the frame that was read to make sure it is normal
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    frames.append(frame)
```

This code works most of the time, however, I have seen it break on a couple different videos as follows:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The numpy array of typenum=2, ndims=3 can not b
e created) in NumpyAllocator::allocate, file D:\Build\OpenCV\OpenCV-2.4.9\module
s//python//src2//cv2.cpp, line 201
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "vidUtils.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.frames, self.fps, self.numFrames = self.getVideoInfo(filepath)
  File "vidUtils.py", line 57, in getVideoInfo
    ret, frame = cv2Cap.read()
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\OpenCV-2.4.9\modules//python//src2//cv2.cpp:201: erro
r: (-2) The numpy array of typenum=2, ndims=3 can not be created in function Num
pyAllocator::allocate
```

I am printing out the frame number that the code fails on and it is not always consistent, which makes me think that there is something else going on that I'm completely missing. It has been lately kirking out at 1780-1820 frames. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
~zoltana

Comment: Try clearing some 50 frames after 50 frames when you reach 500 or 1000 frames. This seems to be a memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you possibly be running out of memory? Allocation errors very often mean "out of memory". Without knowing your video resolution, your frames would typically be between 1..5 MB each, and then at around 2000 frames you would be looking at several gigabytes.

If you are running a 32-bit PYthon, you may bump into the 2 GB barrier rather easily. With a 64-bit Python you are more likely going to suffocate into swapping if you do something very big.

I suggest you do some memory profiling. The simplest way is just to look at the size of a single frame (`frame.nbytes`) and multiply it by the number of frames. Another possibility (depending on the OS) is to use `ps` or equivalent utility to check the total memory use of the Python process. If you want to get serious about the memory use, check `heapy` (part of the `guppy-pe` package).

One diagnostic check you could do is to run the same loop without doing `frames.append(frame)`, because then the memory footprint should be much smaller. If that one runs flawlessly, your problem is most likely that you run out of memory. (Unfortunately, errors in the simple test do not prove that there is no memory problem just that it is not in storing the frames. There may be other leaks.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It was the memory that was running out. I had to integrate reading the images with doing the analysis vs. storing the frames off.